# How to fix PlatformException problem during the Firebase Initialization process?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, dart-pub

I am currently working on a task management application based on the flutter framework. I am trying to connect Firebase with my app. According to the documentation I need to initialize the firebase initialize app along with WidgetFlutterBinding. I am also using Getx package as for my state management purpose so I need to inject the dependency for my authcontroller. But as I am trying to run the app, it's throwing error named PlatformException returning null, null.

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:taskify/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:taskify/screens/splash_screen.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().then(
    (value) => Get.put(AuthController()),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const GetMaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my main.dart file in which I am trying to inject the dependency as well as initializing the firebase and flutterwidgetbinding.
But I am getting below error:

```
E/flutter (20807): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter (20807): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter (20807): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20807): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (20807): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20807): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (20807): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20807): #3      main (package:taskify/main.dart:9:3)
E/flutter (20807): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20807):
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly don't use then when you are using await keyword.

Comment: remove then and write your code inside then after the firebase.initialize() line

Comment: My guess is a firebase configuration issue.